# compiling a file using an ANTLR grammar

Tags: java, makefile, antlr

I've been writing an antlr grammar to eventually be used as part of a compiler for smallC programs. For pulling in the code I was originally using java programs which call the grammar and contain the input string (the smallC code), and this has worked.

Unfortunately, I've just been told that we have to do this using a makefile that can call in the grammar and the .c smallC program and produce an .exe. The deadline for this is very soon and I was just wondering how possible this is and if anyone has any advice for going about it, I've not really done any work with makefiles before.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question you're asking here? It's not clear to me what you need help with.

Comment: Well it's more that I'm not even sure where to begin with this, do you know of any good tutorials or reference material for writing makefiles that work with java and antlr.

Comment: Can you describe the desired workflow in more detail? Suppose I have a new SmallC program. What do I do with it in your world to get it to run?

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a bit rubbish with my description here. Thanks for being patient. 

Ok, so I have my antlr file, the .g grammar in which all my parser/ lexer rules etc are defined. I also have java file that currently takes an input string and outputs the tree (although I'm hoping to modify it to pull the text off a .c file) and I want to create a makefile that will run this, or make a executable that will.

Comment: `Makefile` wont help you much with ANTLR. Instead I suppose you need to use [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) grammar parser (see also on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc)). So your `Makefile` may look like one mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778431).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small demo how to use an ANTLR generated (C) parser to compile and run using `make`:

You need the following 4 files:

### T.g

```java
grammar T;

options {
  language=C;
}

parse
  :  (t=. {printf("token: '\%s'\n", $t.text->chars);})+ EOF
  ;

NUMBER
  :  ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
  ;

WORD
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
  ;

OTHER
  :  .
  ;
```

### input.txt

```
foo 42 BAR 3.141592
```

### main.c

```c
#include "TLexer.h"
#include "TParser.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pANTLR3_UINT8 fileName = (pANTLR3_UINT8)"input.txt";
  pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM input = antlr3AsciiFileStreamNew(fileName);

  if(input == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", (char *)fileName);
    exit(1);
  }

  pTLexer lexer = TLexerNew(input);

  if(lexer == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create the lexer due to malloc() failure1\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM tstream = antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew(ANTLR3_SIZE_HINT, TOKENSOURCE(lexer));

  if(tstream == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory trying to allocate token stream\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  pTParser parser = TParserNew(tstream);

  if(parser == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory trying to allocate parser\n");
    exit(ANTLR3_ERR_NOMEM);
  }

  parser->parse(parser);

  parser->free(parser);   parser = NULL;
  tstream->free(tstream); tstream = NULL;
  lexer->free(lexer);     lexer = NULL;
  input->close(input);    input = NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

### Makefile

```
run: T.g main.c
    java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
    gcc -Wall main.c TLexer.c TParser.c -l antlr3c -o main
    ./main
```

If you now run `make`, the following will be printed (at least on my Ubuntu-box):

```
token: 'foo'
token: ' '
token: '42'
token: ' '
token: 'BAR'
token: ' '
token: '3.141592'
token: '
'
```

Needless to say, `antlr-3.3.jar` needs to be in the same directory as the other .g and .c files and the C compiler needs to find `antlr3c` on your system.

Also, when copy-pasting the `Makefile`, be sure to preserve the indented tabs at the start of the lines.

Comment: I haven't thought that ANTLR can [produce C targets](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR3+Code+Generation+-+C) ;) +1

Comment: @dma_k, yep, there are quite a few targets ANTLR can produce parser for (see: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets ). Not all of them are equally good, but quite a few of them are (one of which is the C target).

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks a lot. I've marked your answer as the correct one, may it guide those future generations in creating makefiles for weird programs.