# Code Blocks - mixing c and c++ files

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, bison, flex-lexer

So far I've been working with g++ (on Windows), but for some reasons I want to use Code:Blocks to use sfml library (quite easy configuration, contrary to clean g++).

I use bison to create file.tab.c and file.tab.h (from file.y), I use flex for lex.yy.c (from file.l) and i have my own files containing functions needed for my project (file.cpp and file.h). 
So with g++ I compile it like that:

```
g++ lex.yy.c file.tab.c file.cpp -o file.exe
```

and it works fine. Now i want to compile these files with Code:Blocks and i get a strange error:

```
file.l:4:18: fatal error: cstdio: No such file or directory
```

Why on earth does it signal an error in file.l when this file isn't even included to my project (it just served to create lex.yy.c which i attached to project)? And I'm not sure about that but... main() is in file.tab.c so this is an entry point - can I specifically ask Code:Blocks to compile everything with g++ like I did in command line and there would be a chance for it to work? I have the latest version of Code:Blocks. 
Thanks in advance

//Edit: I can also add that i get the same error when i compile it from command line like that: gcc lex.yy.c.

Comment: `.c` files should be compiled with `gcc` not `g++`! Just compile separately and link the `.o` results in an extra step.

Comment: Well it worked in cmd perefectly - why shouldn't work now? And how can I compile files seperately and link them later in Code:Blocks?

Comment: I used a rock once to hammer a nail.  Just because something _worked before_ does not mean it is the best way.  If you want to compile your C files as C++ then you should set cmake such that your files belong to C++ language: `set_source_files_properties(file.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )`

Comment: So what about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778431/how-do-i-use-c-in-flex-and-bison?rq=1 ? He sais that it's just enough to use g++ instead of gcc and it works...

Answer (score 2):

To make all the source files in a C::B project be compiled as C++, regardless of file extension
and regardless of whether `gcc` or `g++` is invoked, add the option `-x c++` in
**YourProject** -> **Build options...** -> **Compiler settings** -> **Other options**.

That forces C++ compilation and should solve your problem, but just in case it is not clear to you, the error:

```
fatal error: cstdio: No such file or directory
```

is occurring because the C++ header `<cstdio>` is being `#include`-ed in a compilation
that is being compiled as C, and that header is not in the C compiler's include-search paths.

The C compiler is being chosen based on the file extension (`.c`) of the file being
compiled when the error occurs. The `-x c++` option overrides this, but you might
look for a better solution by investigating how it happens that a C++ header is getting
included in a C source file, and correcting that if you can.

The C header equivalent to `<cstdio>` is `<stdio.h>`. Can you fix the problem simply by 
changing `<cstdio>` to `<stdio.h>` somewhere? If you use the `-x c++` solution then it 
stops you from ever adding a source file to the project that *should* be compiled as C.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all the standard  library files are all included in your project; For help on linking files, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks).

It could be more better if you include more details.

Comment: Well, my project works when i compile it with g++, like I said earlier. I just want to compile it in Code:Blocks the same way like in cmd - I honestly have no clue why these files compiled together with g++ work, and seperately they don't... (it also happens in cmd)