# Algorithm for evaluating expression

Tags: algorithm

I am writing a C++ program that must parse and then evaluate an expression held in a string like this:

```
((C<3) || (D>5)) and (B)
```

or something like

```
((A+4) > (B-2) || C) && ^D
```

The expression will always evaluate to true of false.  I read about shunting yard algorithm, but order of operations isn't that important to me (I can just state left to right evaluation).

I'm thinking about building a tree to hold the components of the formula and then evaluate the tree recursively from bottom left up. Each child of a node would be an AND, each node would be a test. If I reach the topmost node (while current state is true) it must evaluate to true. This is a rough start...looking for advice.

Is there an algorithm design pattern on how to do this? (Seems like this problem has been solved many times before)

Comment: How is it anything other than a regular expression parser?

Comment: Regular expressions can't parse stacked paranthesies ( ).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend putting the time and effort into learning proper lexing and parsing tools that are designed for this. Flex for lexical analysis (getting individual tokens - variable, operation, paranthesis, etc.) and then Bison for syntax analysis (building the syntax tree from tokens).

Once you have the syntax tree, evaluation is easy from bottom to up, as you said.

I'm not sure how much you know about formal gramars, but you can always find good tutorials online, perhaps start here: [How do I use C++ in flex and bison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778431/how-do-i-use-c-in-flex-and-bison)